# Problems implementing service account with google-api-php-client

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk, google-books

This seemed to fix itself... after an hour or so I hit F5 and it worked, I could see a list of book titles.

So I copied the file and modified it in order to get a list of all users

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

session_start();
include_once "templates/base.php";

set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Directory.php';

$client_id = '118xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = '118xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '/Path/ServiceAccount-privatekey.p12';

echo pageHeader("Service Account Access");

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'),
    $key
);
$cred->sub = "adminUser@googleAppsDomain.com";
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

$results = $service->users->listUsers();
echo "<h3>Results Of Call:</h3>";
print_r($results);
echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
```

However, when I run this code I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users: (400) Bad
>   Request' in
>   /var/www/common/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php:80

Thanks again for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you move past the **400 Bad Request** error:

The call `$service->users->listUsers()` needs some parameters - at least `domain` or `customer`.

E.g. `$service->users->listUsers( Array('domain' => 'test.com') )`

That's your immediate problem - that your call to that API is incomplete.

However, after that point I'm willing to bet you'll come into permissions issues. I'm currently trying to untangle them in my project!

Answer (score -1):

Dan Lester and OP: I was running up against this too, and was finally able to get it working.  Essentially, you need to be setting domain, view_type, **and sub**.  (Where sub is a user within the domain to make your request on account of.)  There was code added to the php library as loadServiceAccountJson() to set up service authorization, but it doesn't set sub in its call to Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials, so its useless.

Working code's here: [Google php client library loadServiceAccountJson broken - fix enclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615781/google-php-client-library-loadserviceaccountjson-broken-fix-enclosed)